# Webservice compatibility issue due to name attribute in wsdl

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio, web-services, wsdl

I'm trying to use a third-party java-based webservice from a .net application. The thing is I'm having compatibility issues regarding the given wsdl. When I try to include this wsdl in my VStudio project I'm getting this message:

```
Warning: 'name' attribute is invalid. The value 'envio:Foo_Envio" is invalid for data type' http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:NCName '- The':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, can not be used in a name . Line 17, position 20
```

I've read [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_document-n) that they shouldn't use a colon character in the name attribute, because as a NCName type it's only allowed to use a very short set of them. The thing is when I import this wsdl in a Eclipse web project I've no issues at all. Does any of you have any clue about what's happening in Eclipse that doesn't work in VS?

Thanks in advance.

The concerning wsdl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:Foo="transmision" xmlns:envio="envio.xsd" xmlns:recepcion="recepcion.xsd" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace="transmision">
  <types>
    <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:Foo="transmision" xmlns:envio="transmision" xmlns:FooRecepcion="recepcion.xsd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xsd:import namespace="recepcion.xsd" schemaLocation="recepcion.xsd"/>
      <xsd:import namespace="envio.xsd" schemaLocation="envio.xsd"/>
    </schema>
  </types>
  <message name="Foo_Envio">
    <part name="envio" element="envio:envio"/>
  </message>
  <message name="Foo_Recepcion">
    <part name="recepcion" element="recepcion:confirmacionRecepcion"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="Foo">
    <operation name="Foo">
      <input name="envio:Foo_Envio" message="Foo:Foo_Envio"/>
      <output name="envio:Foo_Recepcion" message="Foo:Foo_Recepcion"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="FooSoapBinding" type="Foo:Foo">
    <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="Foo">
      <input>
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="FooService">
    <port name="Foo" binding="Foo:FooSoapBinding">
      <wsdlsoap:address location="https://ws.whatever.com/iniinvoc/es.foo.Foos.ws.EnvioSOAP"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Eclipse also shows errors on those wsdl lines: cvc-attribute.3: "The value 'envio:Foo_Envio' of attribute 'name' on element 'input' is not valid with 
  respect to its type, 'NCName'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we've contacted with the third-party and they've changed the name attribute, removing the ":" character.